# Are the undecidable languages closed under complement?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, undecidability, closure-properties

Are the undecidable languages closed under complement? 
How can the answer be proved?

Comment: Prove the contrapositive: the complement of a decidable language is decidable.

Comment: Try to prove a more general fact: For any self-inverse function $f : A \to A$, set $B  \subseteq A$ is closed against $P$ if and only if $\overline{B} = A \setminus B$ is closed against $P$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you could decide the complement. Wouldn't you then be able to decide the language itself?